# Question regarding Hilbert scheme of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory, hilbert-schemes

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let us consider $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ quotients of $(\mathbb{P^1})^n$ in the following sense. We consider diagonal action of $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ over $(\mathbb{P^1})^n$ given by $(g,(x_1, x_2,\dotsc,x_n))=(gx_1, gx_2,\dotsc,gx_n)$ for $g\in \SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $(x_1, x_2,\dotsc,x_n)\in (\mathbb{P^1})^n $. We also consider linearization with respect to the ample line bundle $L(m)=O(m_1)\otimes O(m_2)\dotsb O(m_n)$ where $m=(m_1,m_2,\dotsc, m_n)$ and $\lvert m\rvert=\sum_1^nm_i$ and also defined for $x\in (\mathbb{P^1})^n$ the set $I_k(x)=\{i\in(1,2,\dotsc ,n)\mathrel\vert x_i=x_k\}$. Then it is well known that GIT quotient exists with respect to this action and linearization. My questions are following:

1. Can this GIT quotient be realised as the Hilbert scheme of points of some scheme?
2. Is there any relation between this GIT quotient and the Hilbert scheme of points of $\mathbb{P}^n$ or $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$?

Apologies if my questions are naïve. Any comments or reference will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Every separated, locally finitely presented $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $H$ equals the Hilbert scheme parameterizing zero-dimensional closed subschemes of $H$ of length $1$.  So, in that sense, the answer to your first question is "yes."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you give me some reference@JasonStarr?

Comment: @tota Jason's comment is a tautology. When the length is fixed as $1$, your subschemes are ordinary closed points, and any variety is thus trivially the "Hilbert scheme of points on itself."

Comment: Thanks@TabesBridges